# Which solution to parse a text with Regex and save to a Database the capturing group?

Tags: regex, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I've to face the following challenge which I would like to automatize using Regex:

I have to match this two mappings:

1. `GetSQLParameter("@switch", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 1), _
   GetSQLParameter("@IDUtente", SqlDbType.Int), _`
2. `sqlClient.AddParameterWithValue("switch", SqlDbType.TinyInt, user.IDUser);
   sqlClient.AddParameterWithValue("IDUtente", SqlDbType.Int, user.IDUser);`

I would like to use 2 capturing group on the first code to get the name of the parameter and it's DB type.

Then I would like to analyze the second piece of code matching the name of the parameter and it's DB Type just to replace it.

Which kind of solution would you see as optimal to reach this objective?

I also [asked for ready-made tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/is-there-any-tool-to-parse-a-text-with-regex-and-save-to-a-database-the-capturin) on our companion site Software Recommendations.

Comment: I've been advised to move here from Programmer section. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is it all in the same string/file, and which comes first 1 or 2, and are they unique?

Comment: @sln: no, they are w different files but they access to the same Database. The name of the parameters are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code

```
 # ==================================
 # GetSQLParameter\s*\(\s*"@\s*([^\s"]+)\s*"\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,

 GetSQLParameter \s* \( \s* 
 "@ \s* 
 ( [^\s"]+ )                 # (1), Param Name
 \s*
 "
 \s* , \s* 
 ( [^,\s]+ )                 # (2), DB Type
 \s* ,

 # Store:  
 # AryStruct['\1'].newName    = 'newname';
 # AryStruct['\1'].oldDBtype  = '\2';
 # AryStruct['\1'].newDBtype  = 'newtype';


 # ==================================
 # (sqlClient\.AddParameterWithValue\s*\(\s*"\s*)([^"\s]+)(\s*"\s*,\s*)([^,\s]+)(\s*,)

 (                           # (1 start)
      sqlClient \. AddParameterWithValue \s* \( \s* 
      " \s* 
 )                           # (1 end)
 ( [^"\s]+ )                 # (2), Param Name
 (                           # (3 start)
      \s* 
      "
      \s* , \s* 
 )                           # (3 end)
 ( [^,\s]+ )                 # (4), DB Type
 ( \s* , )                   # (5)

 # Replacement:   '\1' + AryStruct['\2'].newName + '\3' +  AryStruct['\2'].newDBtype + '\5'
```

Comment: @user3439274 - I don't think you had enough points yet, I upvoted you to give you some. Thanks.